# Loop para afectar todos os registos de uma tabela

Tags: vb.net, loop

Queria que me ajudassem no seguinte, eu queria executar o código que vos vou mostrar em baixo num botão de maneira que o fizesse automaticamente quando clicasse nele.

O programa funciona da seguinte maneira: primeiro tenho que inserir um código numa textbox para chamar um registo (um médico neste caso) e caso esse médico tenha mais que 80 anos carrego num botão para que faça uma serie de alterações, o que pretendo é que noutro botão, que o programa encontre todos os médicos que tenham mais de 80 anos e faça as tais alterações.

```
Public Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress


    If e.KeyChar.ToString = ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then ' Enter para pesquisar
        TextBox1.Focus()
        e.Handled = True

        CarregarGrid() ' carrega a grid só depois de inserir o código do medico
        Label8.Text = DGV1(0, 0).Value

        If Not IsDBNull(DGV1(9, 0).Value) Then

            Dim cd, bd As Date        '  Calcula a idade fazendo a diferença entre o ano actual e o ano da DBO (date of birth)
            bd = (DGV1(9, 0).Value)
            cd = Now

            Dim idade As Integer = Year(cd) - Year(bd)

            If idade > 80 Then
                Button1.Enabled = True
            Else
                Button1.Enabled = False
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Button1.Enabled = True

End Sub

Public Sub btnAlterarDadosMedico(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    TextBox1.Text = DGV1(5, 0).Value ' para ver o codigo do médico

    AlteracoesGrid(DGV1, DGV3, DGV5)

    DesalocarMedicos()

    CarregarGrid()
```

O código dos métodos:

```
Public Sub CarregarGrid() ' carrega so depois de inserir o codigo do medico

    Form1.DoctorBasicTableAdapter.Fill(Form1.GSM81DataSet.DoctorBasic, Form1.TextBox1.Text.ToString())
    Form1.DoctorEnterpriseIdTableAdapter.Fill(Form1.GSM81DataSet.DoctorEnterpriseId, Form1.DGV1(0, 0).Value)
    Form1.DoctorRepresentativeTableAdapter.Fill(Form1.GSM81DataSet.DoctorRepresentative, Form1.DGV1(0, 0).Value)
    Form1.DoctorsAddressTableAdapter.Fill(Form1.GSM81DataSet.DoctorsAddress, Form1.DGV1(0, 0).Value)
    Form1.DoctorsVisitsTableAdapter.Fill(Form1.GSM81DataSet.DoctorsVisits, Form1.DGV1(0, 0).Value)
    Form1.DoctorEnterpriseDetailsTableAdapter.Fill(Form1.GSM81DataSet.DoctorEnterpriseDetails, Form1.DGV1(0, 0).Value)

End Sub

Public Sub DesalocarMedicos()
    Dim sqlConnection1 As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=GSM81;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=senha")
    Dim cmd, cmd2, cmd3 As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM DoctorEnterpriseDetails WHERE (EnterpriseId <> 26) AND DoctorId = " & Form1.Label8.Text
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1

    cmd2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
    cmd2.CommandText = "DELETE FROM DoctorEnterpriseId WHERE (EnterpriseId <> 26) AND DoctorId = " & Form1.Label8.Text
    cmd2.Connection = sqlConnection1

    cmd3.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
    cmd3.CommandText = "DELETE FROM DoctorRepresentative WHERE (EnterpriseId <> 26) AND DoctorId = " & Form1.Label8.Text
    cmd3.Connection = sqlConnection1

    sqlConnection1.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
    sqlConnection1.Close()

End Sub

Public Sub GravarAddress(DGV5)
    Dim myConnectionString As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=GSM81;user=sa;password=senha")
    Dim myCommand As String
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim MailAdd As Integer
    Dim PlaceT As Integer


    For i = 0 To DGV5.Rows.Count - 2
        'verificar se o campo Mailling Address é nulo ou não
        If IsDBNull(DGV5(11, i).Value) Then
            MailAdd = 0
        ElseIf DGV5(11, i).Value = True Then
            MailAdd = -1
        Else
            MailAdd = 0
        End If

        'verificar se o campo Place Type é nulo ou não
        If IsDBNull(DGV5(10, i).Value) Then
            PlaceT = 0
        ElseIf DGV5(10, i).Value = True Then
            PlaceT = -1
        Else
            PlaceT = 0
        End If

        myCommand = "update doctorsaddress set " & _
            "Address = '" & DGV5(6, i).Value & "', " & _
            "PostalCode = " & DGV5(7, i).Value & ", " & _
            "PlaceTypeId = " & DGV5(8, i).Value & ", " & _
            "Schedule = '" & DGV5(9, i).Value & "', " & _
            "Placeofvisit = " & PlaceT & ", " & _
            "MailingAddress = " & MailAdd & " " & _
            "where addressid = " & DGV5(5, i).Value

        cmd = New SqlCommand(myCommand, myConnectionString)

        cmd.Connection.Open()   'abrir connecção
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()   'escreve na BD
        cmd.Connection.Close()  'fecha a conecção

    Next i
End Sub


Public Sub GravarEnterpriseDetails(DGV3)
    Dim myConnectionString As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=GSM81;user=sa;password=senha")
    Dim myCommand As String
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To DGV3.Rows.Count - 2


        myCommand = "UPDATE DoctorEnterpriseDetails SET " & _
              "RankId = " & DGV3(5, i).Value & ", " & _
              "GroupId = " & DGV3(6, i).Value & ", " & _
              "PrescribingPotential = " & DGV3(9, i).Value & ", " & _
              "ClinicalProfileId = " & DGV3(23, i).Value & ", " & _
              "Telephone = " & DGV3(3, i).Value & ", " & _
              "Mobile = " & DGV3(4, i).Value & ", " & _
              "PlaceOfVisit = " & DGV3(7, i).Value & ", " & _
              "HoursAvailable = " & DGV3(8, i).Value & ", " & _
              "Speciality1 = " & DGV3(10, i).Value & ", " & _
              "Speciality2 = " & DGV3(11, i).Value & ", " & _
              "PostalCodeId = " & DGV3(12, i).Value & ", " & _
              "Observation = '" & DGV3(13, i).Value & "', " & _
              "MailingAddress = " & DGV3(18, i).Value & ", " & _
              "CableTv = " & DGV3(19, i).Value & ", " & _
              "ClinicName = '" & DGV3(20, i).Value & "', " & _
               "Zone = '" & DGV3(21, i).Value & "', " & _
               "Schedule = '" & DGV3(22, i).Value & "' " & _
                "WHERE (EnterpriseId = 26)"

        cmd = New SqlCommand(myCommand, myConnectionString)
        cmd.Connection.Open()   'abrir connecção
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()   'escreve na BD
        cmd.Connection.Close()  'fecha a conexão

    Next i


End Sub

Public Sub GravarDoctorBasic(DGV1)

    Dim myConnectionString As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=GSM81;user=sa;password=senha")
    Dim myCommand As String
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim act As Integer


    If IsDBNull(DGV1(19, i).Value) Then
        act = 0
    ElseIf DGV1(19, i).Value = True Then
        act = -1
    Else
        act = 0
    End If

    myCommand = "UPDATE DoctorBasic SET " & _
    "NOofClinics = " & DGV1(13, 0).Value & ", " & _
    "Lusov = '" & DGV1(20, 0).Value & "', " & _
    "FirstName = '" & DGV1(6, 0).Value & "', " & _
    "LastName = '" & DGV1(7, 0).Value & "', " & _
    "FullName = '" & DGV1(8, 0).Value & "', " & _
     "DOB = " & DGV1(9, 0).Value & ", " & _
     "GraduateDate = " & DGV1(10, 0).Value & ", " & _
    "PlaceofGraduation = '" & DGV1(11, 0).Value & "', " & _
     "LevelofPractice = " & DGV1(12, 0).Value & ", " & _
     "OtherPositions = '" & DGV1(14, 0).Value & "', " & _
     "Emailid = '" & DGV1(15, 0).Value & "', " & _
     "Degree = '" & DGV1(16, 0).Value & "', " & _
     "Observation = '" & DGV1(17, 0).Value & "', " & _
     "LanguageId = " & DGV1(18, 0).Value & ", " & _
     "Active = " & act & " " & _
    "WHERE DoctorId = " & DGV1(0, 0).Value


    cmd = New SqlCommand(myCommand, myConnectionString)
    MsgBox(myCommand)

    cmd.Connection.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Connection.Close()

End Sub

Public Sub AlteracoesGrid(DGV1, DGV3, DGV5)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    ' para preencher a coluna do potencial de prescrição (id = 8 para 5), RankId(48 para Selecção)
    'Perfil clinico = 8, GroupId = 8 (Categoria - Médicos) 



    For i = 0 To DGV3.Rows.Count - 1
        Select Case DGV3(2, i).Value
            Case 26
                DGV3(9, i).Value = 8
                DGV3(5, i).Value = 48
                DGV3(23, i).Value = 8
                DGV3(6, i).Value = 84

        End Select

    Next
    GravarEnterpriseDetails(DGV3)


    'guardar na coluna Lusov (observações)
    Dim Obs As String
    Obs = Trim(DGV1(20, 0).Value.ToString)
    For j = 0 To DGV5.Rows.Count - 2

        If Obs = "" Then

            Obs = checknull(DGV5(6, j).Value.ToString) & " - " & checknull(DGV5(7, j).Value.ToString) & " - " & checknull(DGV5(8, j).Value.ToString)
        Else
            Obs = Obs & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & checknull(DGV5(6, j).Value.ToString) & " - " & checknull(DGV5(7, j).Value.ToString) & " - " & checknull(DGV5(8, j).Value.ToString)

        End If
    Next

    DGV1(20, 0).Value = Obs
    DGV1(13, 0).Value = 0   'para nr de clinicas
    GravarDoctorBasic(DGV1)


    'para a morada 

    For j = 0 To DGV5.Rows.Count - 2
        DGV5(6, j).Value = "NÃO DEFINIDO" ' para a morada
        DGV5(7, j).Value = 421705           'para o codigo postal
        DGV5(8, j).Value = 0            'para o tipo local
        DGV5(9, j).Value = ""   ' para o horário
        DGV5(10, j).Value = True   ' visto para o LocalVisita


    Next
    GravarAddress(DGV5)

End Sub
```

O código que comecei a fazer para o outro botão foi este

```
    Dim myConnectionString As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=******;Initial Catalog=GSM81;user=sa;password=senha")
    Dim myCommand As String
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand


    TextBox1.Text = DGV1(5, 0).Value
    CarregarGrid()
    btnAlterarDadosMedico(sender, e)



    myCommand = "SELECT Code FROM DoctorBasic WHERE CONVERT(int,ROUND(DATEDIFF(hour,DOB,GETDATE())/8766.0,0)) > 80 "

    cmd = New SqlCommand(myCommand, myConnectionString)
    MsgBox(myCommand)
    cmd.Connection.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Connection.Close()
```

Falta-me aqui um loop e isso para fazer o mesmo para todas as linhas da tabela onde estão os médicos mas preciso de ajuda porque não consigo fazer .. acho que dá para fazer com um do while mas está me a faltar a lógica. Se precisarem de mais informação é só dizer.

Comment: achei melhor remover a resposta, pois não consegui te ajudar a resolver o problema, porém você pode melhorar sua pergunta dando uma olhada nesses links: [ask] e [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), talvez fazendo isso outra pessoa consiga te ajudar

Comment: Este seu post está um pouco confuso, só especificar o nome da tabela que eu posso ajudar você. Só falar em poucas palavras, o que deseja fazer?

Comment: Entretanto consegui resolver o problema, esqueci-me foi de colocar aqui a resposta. ainda vou a tempo?

Comment: Se que sabe....